# KeyError and TypeError in my python web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

So sorry about this vague and confusing title. But there is no really better way for me to summarize my problem in one sentence.

I was trying to get the student and grade information from a french website. The link is this (http://www.bankexam.fr/resultat/2014/BACCALAUREAT/AMIENS?filiere=BACS)

My code is as follows:

```
import time
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
regions = {'R\xc3\xa9sultats Bac Amiens 2014':'/resultat/2014/BACCALAUREAT/AMIENS'}
base_url = 'http://www.bankexam.fr'
tests = {'es':'?filiere=BACES','s':'?filiere=BACS','l':'?filiere=BACL'}
for i in regions:
    for x in tests:
        # create the output file
        output_file = open('/Users/student project/'+ i + '_' + x + '.txt','a')
        time.sleep(2) #compassionate scraping
        section_url = base_url + regions[i] + tests[x]  #now goes to the x test page of region i 
        request = urllib2.Request(section_url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
        content = soup.find('div',id='zone_res')
        for row in content.find_all('tr'):
            if row.td:
                student = row.find_all('td')
                name = student[0].strong.string.encode('utf8').strip()
                try:
                    school = student[1].strong.string.encode('utf8')
                except AttributeError:
                    school = 'NA'
                result = student[2].span.string.encode('utf8')
                output_file.write ('%s|%s|%s\n' % (name,school,result))
        # Find the maximum pages to go through
        if soup.find('div','pagination'): 
            import re
            page_info = soup.find('div','pagination')
            pages = []
            for i in page_info.find_all('a',re.compile('elt')):
                try:
                    pages.append(int(i.string.encode('utf8')))
                except ValueError:
                    continue
            max_page = max(pages)
            # Now goes through page 2 to max page
            for i in range(1,max_page):
                page_url = '&p='+str(i)+'#anchor'
                section2_url = section_url+page_url
                request = urllib2.Request(section2_url)
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
                content = soup.find('div',id='zone_res')
                for row in content.find_all('tr'):
                    if row.td:
                        student = row.find_all('td')
                        name = student[0].strong.string.encode('utf8').strip()
                        try:
                            school = student[1].strong.string.encode('utf8')
                        except AttributeError:
                            school = 'NA'
                        result = student[2].span.string.encode('utf8')
                        output_file.write ('%s|%s|%s\n' % (name,school,result))
```

A little more description about the code:
I created a 'regions' dictionary and 'tests' dictionary because there are 30 other regions I need to collect and I just include one here for showcase. And I'm just interested in the test results of three tests (ES, S, L) and so I created this 'tests' dictionary.

Two errors keep showing up, 
one is

```
KeyError: 2
```

and the error is linked to line 12,

```
section_url = base_url + regions[i] + tests[x]
```

The other is

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

and this is linked to line 10.

I know there is a lot of information here and I'm probably not listing the most important info for you to help me. But let me know how I can do to fix this!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the variable `i` in more than one place.

Near the top of the file, you do:

```
for i in regions:
```

So, in some places `i` is expected to be a key into the `regions` dictionary.

The trouble comes when you use it again later. You do so in two places:

```
for i in page_info.find_all('a',re.compile('elt')):
```

And:

```
for i in range(1,max_page):
```

The second of these is what is causing your exceptions, as the integer values that get assigned to `i` don't appear in the `regions` dict (nor can an integer be added to a string).

I suggest renaming some or all of those variables. Give them meaningful names, if possible (`i` is perhaps acceptable for an "index" variable, but I'd avoid using it for anything else unless you're code golfing).